# C# UWP Microsoft User Account Encyprion Key To Decrypt Across Multiple Devices

Tags: c#, encryption, uwp, account

I'm basically trying to encrypt a file within the UWP app that will be saved to OneDrive (already have successful code on saving file to OneDrive location) so that the same user can then load that file into another copy of the same app that is installed on a different Windows PC/Device or within the same app on the same PC (already have successful code on restoring the file into app on different and same device) but have it decrypt automatically for that specific user so that their data is secure while stored in OneDrive. I don't want another logged in user on the same or different PC to be able to restore the file into their copy of the app if it did not originate from their app.   Any actual code would be greatly helpful.   I just need code to encrypt a storagefile within the storagefolder so that the app uses a key or some sort of descriptor for the current Microsoft account that obtained the app from the store across all devices that same user installed the app on.  I do not have any code for the encryption as I do not know where to begin.

Comment: Optimally speaking, no one should have access to a user's OneDrive file other than themselves. Encrypting a file to secure it in a place it already should be secured is kinda redundant.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.   My app also allows them to choose where they want to save the file other than OneDrive if they so choose.  I wanted to give them that extra layer of security in case someone decided they wanted to save the file locally on the hard drive or somewhere else others could have access to.

Answer (score 0):

For data protection, you could refer to [Data protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/data-protection) document, it tells how to use the [`DataProtectionProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/uwp/api/Windows.Security.Cryptography.DataProtection.DataProtectionProvider) class in the `Windows.Security.Cryptography.DataProtection` namespace to encrypt and decrypt digital data in a UWP app. The document contains segment code that you could use directly.

> I don't want another logged in user on the same or different PC to be able to restore the file into their copy of the app if it did not originate from their app.

[**OneDrive**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/services/onedrive) file could be accessed by the specific user, it will not restore the file for other users, it is security for protecting user's data.

Comment: Is there a simple method to convert a file into hexadecimal and then convert it back from hexadecimal to it's original file?

Comment: Sure, please check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/security/copy-to-and-from-byte-arrays) that convert buffer to hexadecimal  string

Comment: How to use Data Protection on a specific file within ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder (Storagefile)?